# Do svn have related link from a repository to another?

Tags: svn, repository

i have an svn repository  svn://10.10.3.3/adapter
and i have tow other repository:
svn://10.10.3.3/business_a
svn://10.10.3.3/business_b
now these two projects are all want to use the adapter, can i add some-link like：
 svn://10.10.3.3/business_a/adapter -->  svn://10.10.3.3/adapter
 svn://10.10.3.3/business_b/adapter -->  svn://10.10.3.3/adapter
so people can use svn co/up svn://10.10.3.3/business_a to get the adapter repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read about SVN externals in SVN Book and use it

Comment: thanks, i use the tortoiseSVN solve this problem in 1m. before this i try according to the SVN Book and top 5 results in google, but i always get some error..